# Draw point in SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In a regular UIView I can do something like the following:

```
    SKShapeNode *point = [SKShapeNode node];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(25,25,1,1));
```

However, in the context of an SKShapeNode I do not seem to be able to do this. Are there any better methods for creating single point rectangles (or just points) in a shape node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [SKSpriteNode with a color and size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKSpriteNode/spriteNodeWithColor%3asize%3a) of (1,1) to draw a "pixel" (actually a point).

Answer (score 1):

Sprite Kit doesn't provide a Core Graphics or OpenGL ES context you can issue drawing commands in. To draw multiple dots, your best bet is probably to create a sprite or shape node for each, and add them as child nodes of the one you want to have dots on top of.

If you have a lot of dots and they don't move around with respect to the parent node, using an `SKEffectNode` for the parent might help with performance, since it rasterizes its child node subtree and reuses it for later drawing.